# _doc + Spring data elasticsearch + find document

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to convert below query to Spring Data elasticsearch

```
GET indexName/_doc/{id}?_source_includes=jsonField1,jsonField2
```

Answer (score 0):

source filtering for get requests is currently not supported in Spring Data Elasticsearch.

**Edit 09.12.2021:**

If you don't need source filtering, to get a Document by id you can either use

`ElasticsearchOperations#get(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<T>)`

or

`ElasticsearchRepository#findById(ID)`

Comment: what about without source filtering

GET indexName/_doc/{id}

Comment: I mean is there any method in spring data elasticsearch in which we can find document by id. I dont want to user SearchQuery.